# Does Time Delay Between Particle Emissions Affect the Double-Slit Experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Has there been any experimental confirmation that the time delay between the release of individual particles doesn't affect the resulting interference pattern in a double-slit experiment? If so, could you point me towards the relevant research or sources? I'm specifically interested in understanding if the interference pattern remains consistent regardless of how long we wait between sending each quantum particle (e.g., photon, electron) through the slits

Comment: The Chandra spectroscopic gratings are multiple slit apertures, not double, but they produce spectra via diffraction even at very low photon rates, <one per second.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length

Comment: If 1000 scientists each did a double slit experiment each with only one photon ..... when the got together to compare results they would indeed discover the pattern.  Every photon acts on its own, per Feynman path integral certain paths get higher probabilities.

Comment: single electrons at a time  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles ,  single photons at a time https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/